# How bad is a non-Lagrangian Point orbit?

Tags: orbit, delta-v, lagrangian-points, station-keeping

I am no expert on space physics, just an interested amateur. I've been searching for a few weeks and having a hard time gaining insight on this question. Phrasing the question more specifically: how much greater is the annual delta-V budget for station keeping in a heliocentric orbit in line with Earth (i.e. orbital radius 1AU) for an orbital position away from any Lagranian point, compared to being at a Lagrangian point?

The closest thing to a useful answer I could find is [this paper](https://www.swsc-journal.org/articles/swsc/full_html/2015/01/swsc140007/swsc140007.html) proposing "A concept mission consisting of six spacecraft in a heliocentric orbit at 0.72 AU". It includes a table of mission-lifetime station-keeping fuel budgets for each of the six spacecraft to maintain them evenly separated in Venus orbit. None of the proposed spacecraft are actually on any of the Lagrangian points, but the fuel budgets range from 14 to 20 kg, or a range of very roughly +/- 40%.

I'm surprised at how much information there is out there for the general public about pseudo-orbits around Lagrangian points, including quite a lot of information about delta-V/thrust/fuel budgets for transfer/insertion as well as station-keeping. And I'm also surprised at how little information there is about orbits outside of Lagrangian points!

Incidentally, a corollary question would be: given that the actual goal is to maintain a symmetric network of N satellites (6 in the case of the linked article) in heliocentric orbit close (or close-ish) to Earth, is it more affordable to hold them in non-Lagrangian-point orbits, or is it more affordable to change the radius a little bit and have them in earth-leading or -trailing orbits?